# How can I hide the extra NavigationBar in SwiftUI

Tags: swiftui, swiftui-list, swiftui-navigationview

I have a problem I have in my code. 2 navigation links that go to different views.

Does someone know how I can make the first navigation link not appear to me?

[image: preview 1]

This is my code:

[image: preview 2]

[image: preview 3]

```
struct ContentView: View {
@State var navigationFlag = false
var body: some View {

        


    NavigationView {
                VStack {
                    Text("First View")
                    
                    Button(action: {
                        self.navigationFlag = true
                    }, label: {
                        Text("navigate")
                    })
                    
                    NavigationLink(destination: SwiftUIView(),
                                   isActive: self.$navigationFlag,
                                   label: {
                                    EmptyView()
                                   })
    
        
    }
}
}
```

}

struct SwiftUIView: View {

```
var body: some View {
    NavigationView{
 
        NavigationLink(destination:Swift2UIView()) {
    Text("hola")
    }
    }
```

}

Comment: Remove the NavigationView that creates it. You only need one for your whole app

Comment: hey buddy, do not put code as image, edit your question and past your code.

Comment: Post code instead of screenshot and give NavigationView only the first parent view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to hide `NavigationView`, you can use [`navigationBarHidden`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/view/navigationbarhidden(_:)) view modifier like so:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            VStack {
                    ...
            } // set an empty string as title and then hide nav bar
            .navigationBarTitle("")
            .navigationBarHidden(true)
        }
    }
    
}
```